# I am having difficulty accessing a SQLite3 table in my Jupyter notebook (I am using Pandas)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sqlite, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I have a file called im.db in my current working directory, as shown here:
[image]

I also am able to query this database directly from sqlite3 at the command line:

```
% sqlite3
SQLite version 3.28.0 2019-04-15 14:49:49
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite\> .open im.db
sqlite\> select count(\*) from writers;
255873
```

However, when running the same query inside of my notebook:

```
import sqlite3 as sql
con = sql.connect("im.db")
writers_dataframe = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT COUNT(\*) from writers", con)
```

I get an error message which states `no such table: writers`
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!